# BitBlt code not working

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, pinvoke, bitblt

I'm trying to use this code to draw a `Bitmap` directly onto a `PictureBox`:

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Ken\Desktop\Load2.bmp");
Graphics grDest = Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox1.Handle);
Graphics grSrc = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
IntPtr hdcDest = grDest.GetHdc();
IntPtr hdcSrc = grSrc.GetHdc();
BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height,
    hdcSrc, 0, 0, (uint)TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY); // 0x00CC0020
grDest.ReleaseHdc(hdcDest);
grSrc.ReleaseHdc(hdcSrc);
```

but instead of rendering the `Bitmap`'s contents it just draws a solid block of nearly-black.  I'm pretty sure the problem is with the source hDC, because if I change SRCCOPY to WHITENESS in the above code, it draws a solid white block, as expected.

Note:  this next snippet works fine, so there's nothing wrong with the bitmap itself:

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Ken\Desktop\Load2.bmp");
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because a device context contains a 1x1 black bitmap until `SelectObject` is used. For whatever reason, `Graphics.FromImage` is giving you a device context that is compatible with the bitmap, but it does not automatically select the bitmap into the device context.

The following code will use `SelectObject`.

You should, of course, use the managed `Graphics.DrawImage` instead of `BitBlt` if possible, but I assume that you have a good reason for using `BitBlt`.

```
private void Draw()
{
    using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\Jason\forest.jpg"))
    using (Graphics grDest = Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox1.Handle))
    using (Graphics grSrc = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        IntPtr hdcDest = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr hdcSrc = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr hBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr hOldObject = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            hdcDest = grDest.GetHdc();
            hdcSrc = grSrc.GetHdc();
            hBitmap = bmp.GetHbitmap();

            hOldObject = SelectObject(hdcSrc, hBitmap);
            if (hOldObject == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new Win32Exception();

            if (!BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height,
                hdcSrc, 0, 0, 0x00CC0020U))
                throw new Win32Exception();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (hOldObject != IntPtr.Zero) SelectObject(hdcSrc, hOldObject);
            if (hBitmap != IntPtr.Zero) DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            if (hdcDest != IntPtr.Zero) grDest.ReleaseHdc(hdcDest);
            if (hdcSrc != IntPtr.Zero) grSrc.ReleaseHdc(hdcSrc);
        }
    }
}

[DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "SelectObject")]
public static extern System.IntPtr SelectObject(
    [In()] System.IntPtr hdc,
    [In()] System.IntPtr h);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DeleteObject")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool DeleteObject(
    [In()] System.IntPtr ho);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "BitBlt")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool BitBlt(
    [In()] System.IntPtr hdc, int x, int y, int cx, int cy,
    [In()] System.IntPtr hdcSrc, int x1, int y1, uint rop);
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. Can you explain the first line in the `finally` block?

Comment: Deleting an object that is currently selected into a device context is not correct, according to MSDN. See the remarks at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162957(VS.85).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183539(VS.85).aspx. The line of code restores the original 1x1 bitmap prior to deleting the bitmap identified by hBitmap.

Comment: @JasonKresowaty how about `BitBlt` being about 25x faster for drawing many small images?